# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(b_n)-f(a_n)}{b_n-a_n} =f'(c)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f$ be differentiable at $c$ and let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be sequences such that $a_n<c<b_n$ and $a_n,b_n \rightarrow c$. Prove $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(b_n)-f(a_n)}{b_n-a_n} = f'(c)$

I know this problem is very similar to mean value theorem. However, it shows up before that chapter. I am wondering how to prove this one without using Rolle theorem and Mean Value theorem. I hope someone can give me some hint to think about.

Comment: $f(b_n) - f(a_n) = \bigl(f(b_n) - f(c)\bigr) + \bigl(f(c) - f(a_n)\bigr)$

Comment: I have considered this way before, but how to deal with denominator?

Comment: Write $$\frac{f(b_n) - f(c)}{b_n - a_n} = \frac{b_n - c}{b_n - a_n}\cdot \frac{f(b_n) - f(c)}{b_n-c}$$ and analogously for $c - a_n$.

Comment: Proper MathJax usage is "Let $f$ be differentiable at $c$", not "Let f be differentiable at c", and $$ \{ a_n\}$$ has the {curly braces} INSIDE of MathJax.